# Why this constexpr does not create an error?

Tags: c++, templates

As you know, `memcpy()` is not a `constexpr`. Any idea why this code compiles without error?

```
template<typename T>
constexpr void mymemcopy(T* a, void* b) {
    memcpy(a, b, sizeof(T));
}
```

I tested in both `clang 12.0.0` and `gcc 11.1` with `-pedantic` flag. It compiles in `MSCV 19.28` too. I have rarely seen a similar bug for all compilers...

A full working sample is here:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr void mymemcopy(T* a, void* b) {
    memcpy(a, b, sizeof(T));
}

int main()
{
    double a, b = 10.0;

    mymemcopy(&a, &b);

    std::cout << a;
}
```